VB .NET Web Application - Open Android App
I have a visual basic .NET web application that has a hyperlink that will bring the user to a different website. When the user is on an android device, the website does not work if they're using their device remotely. Since that's the case, these remote users have the android app version of this website. On our web application, instead of navigating them to this other website, since it won't work anyways, I wanted to have the button open the android application instead. How do I go about this? Here is my current code:
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlNavToWebsite" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("id","https://website.com/Default.aspx?document=FRM&id={0}&type=form") %>' Target="_blank">
    <h5>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="" />
    </h5>
</asp:HyperLink>

I created a function that checks to see if the user is a remote user so it would automatically choose the application version instead of the link. It's a function that's just called IsRemote(EmployeeID) where EmployeeID is stored in a label (lblEID.Text).

Some information is missing here. VB.net does not run nor work on Android, so I'm failing to grasp what you are saying here. If user's on their Android are say using some kind of remote desktop to the vb.net desktop application, then if they click on a hyper-link in that desktop application, then the PC would of course launch the browser, and the browser should/would appear in the remote desktop session that you using with the Android. However, it not at all clear what vb.net has to do with the Android here? (unless as I am guessing that such users are using Android to remote into their PC

So is the web site written in vb.net? And if not, then what does vb.net have to do with this question then? Perhaps you are suggesting that a whole new Android application was written, or that when users hit the hyper-link when using their Android web browser, then the hyper link does not work then????

I have a web application written in vb.net, lets call it MyApp. MyApp has a list of workorders on the technician's dashboard page. In the list of work orders, currently there is a button to open the work order in the separate web application. Lets call that one TheirApp. TheirApp also has an android application. Our technicians cannot access TheirApp and need to access TheirApp's mobile android app instead. I wanted, in MyApp, to instead of routing them to TheirApp, to open TheirApp's android app instead which is already downloaded and logged in on their tablets.

Web browsers can't out of the blue start running some software on my windows desktop, or on my Android phone. If web sites could launch software on the client side, then when you come to my site to view some cute cat pictures, then I would start launching + running all kinds of software on your client computer - such as software to steal your files called "my banking"  or steal all outlook contacts. So some web site to all of a sudden launch + run some software on the client side computer/phone is a huge security risk and not possible. No one would use internet if this was possible.
